# SQL Server logins disabled

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

While disabling the logins of a server, I mistakenly disabled sysadmin logins as well. Now, none of the sysadmins can login. It would be helpful if anyone can suggest me the alternative to revert back the changes or to enable the sysadmin logins again.

This would be of great help. Thank you. :)

Comment: login with windows administrative account and enable back

Comment: Hi, your suggestion is so helpful, but I have disabled all server logins including windows groups. Can you please suggest any other way, if possible?

Comment: you just need a local admin account on the server.  single user mode will let a local admin login regardless of what user permissions are in normal mode.

Comment: Yeah. Got you. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Put SQL Server into Single User Mode.  You will need to do this as a local administrator on the server where SQL Server is running.

This mode allows only a single account to connect. If the account is a local administrator on the server, you will have permission to re-add an account back into the sysadmin group. You must then restart SQL Server back into multi-user mode.

Detailed instructions are [provided here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/connect-to-sql-server-when-system-administrators-are-locked-out).